# Last line of code wont execute?

Tags: python

Hi I'm having a problem with the last line of the code. It won't print anything.

```
invalid=True
global invalid
def start()
  x = input('Type the correct key:')
  if ("m" == x) or ("M"==x):
   print('Correct!')
  elif x!='m' or x!='M':
   print('Invalid Input.')
   invalid=False
 while invalid:
  start()
print('Next Question')
```

When the input is 'm' or 'M' it should say Correct!
  Next question but it doesn't it just prints Correct!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: That while loop seems like an indentation error. Can you format the code correctly?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: `global` declarations go inside each function that wants to use the global, not at global scope. (`global` at global scope should really be a SyntaxError, but it's not.)

Comment: This is how i run the code in PyCharm and it works with the exact indentations.

Comment: The indentation as shown isn't correct. the `while invalid` loop *cannot* be indented more than `def start` but less than the first line of the body of `start`.

Comment: Please count the number of spaces at the start of `x = input(...)` and the number of spaces at the start of `while invalid:`. What are those counts?

Comment: There is a missing `:` at the end of the `def start()` line. Please copy-paste your program (_never_ retype) into your question.

Answer (score 1):

I ran you code in IDLE and the indentation were off, also as user2357112 mentioned, global should go inside a function but I dont see why you are using it.

Also you should have a condition for your while loop to end. Right now the loop will not end.

```
def start():
    invalid=True
    global invalid
    x = input('Type the correct key:')
    if ("m" == x) or ("M"==x):
        print('Correct!')
    else:
        print('Invalid Input.')
        invalid=False
    while invalid:
        start()
        print('Next Question')
```

This might help

```
def startm():
    valid = True
    while(valid):
        x = input('Type the correct key:')
        if ("m" == x) or ("M"==x):
            print('Correct!')
        else:
            print('Invalid Input.')
            valid=False
```

You can start the while loop with condition `True` and as long as its valid the loop will continue to run. Once the loop becomes `False`. It will break out.

Comment: How should i add a condition for the while loop to end?

Comment: @DamjanDjurdjevic, please accept the answer if it helped and you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things here:

1. You have a logic error; invalid should be initialized as `False` and set to `True` if the `elif` is triggered.
2. You're calling `start()` from within itself, which is unnecessary; instead, the `while` could be around the whole definition (encompassing the `if-elif`), with `invalid` being set to `False` inside the `if`.

Answer (score -1):

you have to set the global variable first and then set it as True. This will work

```
global invalid 
invalid = True
def start():
  x = input('Type the correct key:')
  if ("m" == x) or ("M"==x):
   print('Correct!')
  elif x!='m' or x!='M':
   print('Invalid Input.')
   invalid=False
while invalid:
  start()
print('Next Question')
```

does that solve your problem?

Comment: This will not work, this will lead to error where variable is referenced before assignment or something.

Comment: did you fix the indents ?